# Submitting data from 1 table to another table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to submit data from a checklist using forms. The checklist is generated from a database table and after submission the checked items are inserted into another database table. I am getting the error as *form is invalid.*

This is my models.py CustomStudent is the database from where I am taking value and Reports is the database where I am submitting values

```
class CustomStudent(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField
    sname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    slname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.slname)
        return str(self.sname)

class Report(models.Model):
    # _id = models.AutoField()
    tname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    sname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    fdate = models.DateField()
    tdate = models.DateField()
    dailydate = models.DateField()
    objective = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    tplan = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    how = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    material = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    extra = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    pftd = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    thought = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    admin_comment = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tname)
        return str(self.sname)
```

This is code from my forms.py to use the database.

```
sname = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=CustomStudent.objects.all().values_list('sname', flat=True), required = False,  widget =forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple( attrs ={'class':' form-check-input'  ' form-check-inline'}))
```

This error is generated due to the value of the checklist string is returning in double quotes. ex. "student" from 1st database.

I have tried splitting string to remove double quotes but even that doesn't help.

Comment: Note that in `def __str__(self):` only the first `return` will be used, the second `return` is never reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` needs a model for the choices.

If you want to assign strings, you can use [`forms.MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) instead.

```
sname = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    # list of tuples; the first of each pair is the value to be
    # returned when selected, the second is the value to be displayed
    choices=[
        (e, e)
        e for e in CustomStudent.objects.all().values_list('sname', flat=True)],
    required=False,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        attrs={'class':' form-check-input'  ' form-check-inline'}))
```

See detailed description of the attribute [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Your solution worked.